# Second Yield Is Not Working In JavaScript Generator Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I was learning javascript and if found new concept in function as generator functions
As New Feature In ES6

```
var num=5;
function * x()
{ 
   yield num++;
   yield num*=num; 
};
```

> x().next();

```
{value: 5, done: false}
```

> x().next();

It Should Return {value: 36, done: false}
but returning

```
{value: 6, done: false} // It Should Return {value: 36, done: false}
```

Comment: assign `x()` to a new variable and then try, `a = x(), a.next(), a.next()`?

Comment: thank you @loganfsmyth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call to `x()` creates a *new* generator that will start at the beginning, so for

```
var num=5;
function * x()
{ 
   yield num++;
   yield num*=num; 
};

console.log(x().next());
console.log(x().next());
```

is essentially identical to doing

```
var num = 5;
console.log(num++);
console.log(num++);
```

To get 36, you need to create a single generator and then call `next()` on it, e.g.

```
var gen = x();
console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next());
```